# Implementing a map control in XNA which is zoomable and shows current location

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, geolocation, bing-maps

I would like to add a map control as part of my XNA game which shows the player's current location and updates accordingly via the GeoCoordinateWatcher class. So far all I've managed to do is show a map image from the Bing REST api but to convert latitude and longitude to screen coordinates I need to know the minimum and maximum latitude and longitude, something which I don't think is possible to calculate if the map is zoomable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so after a LOT of searching I managed to find [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Bing-Maps-for-Games-with-bedba16c) gem hidden in MSDN. Basically a small part of the code implements its own tiling system in XNA and has useful methods for converting latitude/longitude to screen x/y. Just what I needed!

Comment: Is there any way to do this offline, without using some sort of webservice? I have a custom created tileset that uses the Bing Maps tiling scheme and I would like this tile layer in an offline game. Any pointers on this?